# Can I move disks from one HP server model to another without data loss?

Tags: hard-drive, hp

I have a HP ML350 G5 Server with 3x 146GB SCSI disks. The server is down because of a power supply failure and I want to recover the information on the disks.

I have another server which is a HP ML380 G6 - can I remove the SCSI disks from the ML350 and put them in the ML380 to recover the information?

Both servers are configured with RAID 5 arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If the RAID controller is an add-on card, pull it and the drives and connect to another server.

The RAID information is usually stored on the HDDs themselves. If the RAID controller is identical, you may be able to connect the drives to the other machine and pull data. If the controller isn't the same, label your drives and send them to a data recovery company.

Or buy a new power supply.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both servers use HP disk controllers you can actually just move the disks as on their kit they write the array layout information to both the controller and all of the disks in the array. This way you can just move the disks and the array will know how to use them properly (although you sometimes get an informational error on boot the first time like this, just to remind you).